# Userform list box is being populated with empty rows via RowSource

Tags: excel, vba

I create a `ListBox` that is supposed to be populated with a range from another Workbook using `RowSource` but I get empty rows instead of a populated list.
My empty rows mean if I got 8 items in my range, the list got 8 empty rows in my list.
I inserted my code into `UserForm_Initialize()` and use `Workbooks.Open` to open the target Workbook first.

I tried changing fore-color, back-color, cells formatting, ...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim tmpRange As Range
    'check database file availability then open database
    DstWBName = "\DB.list." & Year(Now) & ".xlsx"
    If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & DstWBName) = "" Then GoTo ErrFileNotFound
    SetAttr ThisWorkbook.Path & DstWBName, vbNormal
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set DstWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & DstWBName, ReadOnly:=False)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'populate list
    Me.lstCompListBox.RowSource = ""
    Set tmpRange = DstWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2")
    Set tmpRange = Range(tmpRange, tmpRange.End(xlDown))
    Me.lstCompListBox.RowSource = tmpRange.Address
    'Me.lstCompListBox.AddItem "test123"
    '.additem work but not the rowsource

    Exit Sub

    'error handle for missing file
ErrFileNotFound:
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path & DstWBName & " Not Found!"
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

My coding age is 1 week old, kindly help me in my messy code.

**My Userform with empty row**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your line

```
Me.lstCompListBox.RowSource = tmpRange.Address
```

to

```
Me.lstCompListBox.RowSource = tmpRange.Address(external:=True)
```

The reason behind this is that you load the data from an external Workbook so that you can't simply use a range address like `B2:B6` as this still refers to your local WB. With `external:=True` the returned address will fully qualify the file, Worksheet and range address of the data.

Comment: I been working on this whole day and start to drive me crazy. But your solution just work perfectly. Thank.

Comment: Something i want to know more. i already set my range to certain workbook certain sheet, but why i still need add (external:=true) to qualify the file? why not VBA editor return a error?